# To pull data into Microsoft Excel 2007 with web queries

Tags: excel, vba

How can i perform to enter username and password when want to pull data into Microsoft Excel with web queries??? Have any solution can be used to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: why would you need a username and a password ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can pass the usr and pwd as arguments to the query (i.e, via ?username=yourname or something like that) then just construct the string web query (there is a library to do this kind of things, HTTPQuery or something like that)

Answer (score 0):

Set excel to macro recording mode, developer tab > record macro.  Then goto the Data tab and click "From Web". After you do this process, you can look at the code and adjust it accordingly.